Block in one color and transparent
I want the blocks in my beamer to be of only one color, that is, the block title and the block have the same color. In addition to defining the same color, it is necessary to remove the transition between the title and the body.
Additionally, I would also like the block to be transparent, I came across the following code.
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red}
    
\addtobeamertemplate{block begin}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}}{\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
    
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareverticalshading[lower.bg,upper.bg]{bmb@transition}{200cm}{color(0pt)=(lower.bg); color(4pt)=(lower.bg); color(4pt)=(upper.bg)}
\makeatother
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \begin{block}{Title}
        Block stuff.
      \end{block}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}

But you can see that there are two non-transparent lines and I can't get rid of them.

The answer given by samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz is very good, it does exactly what I asked. But the problem is that I made several configurations using \useinnertheme{rounded}. Is there a way to keep this code and maybe create a new MyBlock environment with the tcolorbox configurations?

You could use the tcolorbox inner beamer theme. This will replace the normal beamer blocks with tcolorboxes and you have all the options of tcolorboxes available to customise the blocks:
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rounded}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=red}

\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-duck}}

\useinnertheme[shaded=false]{tcolorbox}

\tcbsetforeverylayer{
  opacityfill=0.5
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{block}{Title}
  Block stuff.
  \end{block}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



This is a great answer. But the problem is that I did all my layout configuration with \useinnertheme{rounded}, removing this code and inserting your my title frame messes up everything. Do you know how to apply it to all frames except the title? Or some other way to get around this problem.

@Mrcrg Maybe try \useinnertheme[titlepage=false]{tcolorbox}, but that's just a guess without seeing your code.
